# Visual Studio SSRS 2016 - Switch Data Source on Environment Change

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS project in a Visual Studio 2017. I have 4 copies of the database I can report against a local one, a development one, a QA one, and a production one. In the solution I have 4 environments setup in Configuration Manager to match, they are debug, Development, QA, and release. Is there a way to setup my SSRS solution and/or SSRS reports so that when I switch between environments from the Solutions Configurations drop down, it switches the environment my report runs against?

This would give my SSRS projects a similar functionality to how my app.config and web.config files work.